# Homekit accessorry simulator details

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, homekit

I have query regarding to homekit simulator such as some keys and parameters mentioned are not understood. So where can I find all of them?

Some concepts for `garage door` and `characteristics` are not understood.
ex. What is current door state?
    what is current lock state?

Answer (score 0):

Use Homekit Accessory Simularot 1.1(54.3)
Go to -> Preferance -> select "Create all option char when adding service"
It will add all characteristic(specific to that service) when you add the service to any accessory.

For Garage door, there is "Garage door opener service".
It has  current door state, target door state, Obstruction detected, Lock Mech current state, Lock Mech target state as it characteristics.

Current door state is read only char, which will used to check the state of door is open or closed? So that you can take appropiate action 
on Target door state to open it or close.

You may refer to Lock mechanism current state here (current lock state).
Used to security check of garage door (if accessory supported).
To check if door is secured(can not open with out key or app or security code) ? unsecured ? (door may be closed but can be open with out key or code etc).
jammed? (Its not functioning properly, may be jammed).

You can refer to HMCharacteristic.h file it as defined the characterisitcs with proper comments.